# convolution in R

Tags: r, fft, convolution

I tried to do convolution in R directly and using FFTs then taking inverse. But it seems from simple observation it is not correct. Look at this example:

```
# DIRECTLY
> x2$xt
[1] 24.610 24.605 24.610 24.605 24.610
> h2$xt
[1] 0.003891051 0.003875910 0.003860829 0.003845806 0.003830842
> convolve(h2$xt,x2$xt)
[1] 0.4750436 0.4750438 0.4750435 0.4750437 0.4750435

# USING INVERSE FOURIER TRANSFORM
> f=fft(fft(h2$xt)*fft(x2$xt), inv=TRUE)
> Re(f)/length(f) 
[1] 0.4750438 0.4750435 0.4750437 0.4750435 0.4750436
>
```

Lets take the index 0. At 0, the convolution should simply be the last value of x2$xt (24.610) multiplied by first value of h2$xt (0.003891051) which should give convolution at index 0 = 24.610*0.003891051 = 0.09575877 which is way off from 0.4750436.

Am I doing something wrong? Why is the values so different from expected?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both `convolve` and `fft` are *circular*. The first element of convolution must be the dot product of these two series. The results you obtain are correct in this sense.

To perform a linear convolution use:

```
convolve(h2$xt,x2$xt,type="open")
```

Circular convolution is also applied in this case but a required amount of zeros are padded to inputs to achieve linear convolution.

I believe there is not a direct way to achieve linear convolution with `fft` in R. However this doesn't really matter beacuse `convolve` itself uses the FFT approach you posted.

---

### Circular Convolution

A discrete signal **x** is periodic if there is a period **N** such that **x[n] = x[n+N]** for all **n**. Such signals can be represented by **N** samples from **x[0]** to **x[N-1]**.

```
... x[-2] x[-1] x[0] x[1] x[2] ... x[N-2] x[N-1] x[N] x[N+1] ...
                ^    this part is sufficient   ^
```

A regular definition of *convolution* between aperiodic **x** and **y** is defined as:

```
(x * y)[n] = sum{k in [-inf, inf]}(x[k]y[n-k])
```

However, for periodic signals, this formula does not produce finite results. To overcome this problem we define the *circular convolution* between periodic **x** and **y**.

```
(x * y)[n] = sum{k in [0, N-1]}(x[i]y[n-k])
```

When these two signals are represented with **N** values only, we can use **y[n-k+N]** in place of **y[n-k]** for negative values of **n-k**.

The cool thing with circular convolution is that it can calculate the *linear convolution* between box signals, which are discrete signals that have a finite number of non-zero elements.

Box signals of length **N** can be fed to circular convolution with **2N** periodicity, **N** for original samples and **N** zeros padded at the end. The result will be a circular convolution with **2N** samples with **2N-1** for linear convolution and an extra zero.

Circular convolution is generally faster than a direct linear convolution implementation, because it can utilize the *Fast Fourier Transform*, a fast algorithm to calculate the *Discrete Fourier Transform*, which is only defined for periodic discrete signals.

---

Please see:

- http://www.centerspace.net/blog/nmath/convolution-correlation-and-the-fft/

Also see:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_convolution
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: thanks. is there a linear version of FFT such that the inverse of that would give linear convolution result?

Comment: Also, I still can't clearly understand the difference between linear and circular convolution. Could you explain it briefly?

Comment: @user236215: Please see the new answer.